# Sending message to AWS Lambda from AWS Pinpoint Custom Channel

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-pinpoint

I am trying to send messages to my AWS Lambda Function from AWS Pinpoint through custom channel as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/developerguide/channels-custom.html)

My problem is about granting permission to AWS Pinpoint to invoke my lambda function. The AWS CLI command provided in the documentation for granting permission is not working. When I execute the `aws lambda add-permission` command from AWS CLI like described in the documentation, I got the following error:

"*`no matches found: arn:aws:mobiletargeting:us-east-1:<account-id>:apps/*`*"

The result doesn't change if I change the ARN to any of the below:

- `arn:aws:mobiletargeting:us-east-1:<account-id>:apps/<pinpoint-app-id>/*`
- `arn:aws:mobiletargeting:us-east-1:<account-id>:apps/<pinpoint-app-id>/campaigns/*`
- `arn:aws:mobiletargeting:us-east-1:<account-id>:/apps/<pinpoint-app-id>/*`
- `arn:aws:mobiletargeting:us-east-1:<account-id>:/apps/<pinpoint-app-id>/campaigns/*`

I tried the same with AWS Cloudformation instead of AWS CLI, I succeeded to grant permission to AWS Pinpoint to invoke my lambda function. At least the Resource Based Policy appeared in the "Permissions" tab of my AWS Lambda Function Console. The source ARN like condition is
`arn:aws:mobiletargeting:us-east-1:<account-id>:apps/<pinpoint-app-id>/*`

But, when I try to create a campaign under the same pinpoint application (i.e., project) I got the following error message:

*`"Amazon Pinpoint couldn’t invoke the Lambda function that you specified for custom delivery. Verify that a function policy is assigned to the function and that Amazon Pinpoint is authorized to invoke the function."`*

I tried different SourceArn like condition including the followings, but the result is the same:

- `arn:aws:mobiletargeting:us-east-1:<account-id>:apps/<pinpoint-app-id>/*`
- `arn:aws:mobiletargeting:us-east-1:<account-id>:apps/<pinpoint-app-id>/campaigns/*`
- `arn:aws:mobiletargeting:us-east-1:<account-id>:apps/*`
- `arn:aws:mobiletargeting:us-east-1:<account-id>:*`
- `arn:aws:mobiletargeting:us-east-1:<account-id>:/apps/*`

Couldn't figure out what the problem is. Any idea about what I am missing will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting but the same `aws lambda add-permission` command that returned `no matches found: arn:aws:mobiletargeting:us-east-1:<account-id>:apps/*` is working after `sudo su`.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably too late, but for anyone that has a similar problem and don't want to go through the whole cloudformation template at least for now.

I had the same issue with

> "no matches found: arn:aws:mobiletargeting:us-east-1::apps/*".

It was due to my terminal behaving weirdly with '*', so adding single quotes around the arn worked, like:
`arn:aws:mobiletargeting:us-east-1:<account-id>:apps/<pinpoint-app-id>/*`

Comment: sorry for the hard to read format, new to stackoverflow posting.